# How to fetch data from sqlite table using IN

Tags: sqlite, sql-in

I have used this query for fetch data from sqlite data table:

```
select cat_eng_name from category_list  where id in (select category_id from       kirtan_list)
```

But I'm not able to get any result or any error, data is available in table as per above condition.

The table can be created with:

```
CREATE TABLE "kirtan_list" ( `id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, `category_id` TEXT, `title_guj`   TEXT, `title_eng`   TEXT, `description_guj` TEXT, `description_eng` TEXT, `kirtan_group`    INTEGER, `pad_no`   INTEGER, `kirtan_audio` TEXT );
INSERT INTO `kirtan_list` VALUES (1,'1,2','kjdsfh','Test','kdsgf','Test',1,1,'1.mp3');
INSERT INTO `kirtan_list` VALUES (2,'3','skdjgf','askjdh','kasjdh','kasjdh',1,2,'2.mp3');
COMMIT; 


CREATE TABLE `category_list` ( `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, `cat_guj_name`    TEXT, `cat_eng_name`    TEXT );
INSERT INTO `category_list` VALUES (1,'All Kirtan','All Kirtan');
INSERT INTO `category_list` VALUES (2,'stuti','Stuti');
```

to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you post a minimal complete example? That is, a sequence of commands, that create the tables involved and insert a few rows into them, so that when the above query is ran, it produces no output.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you provided in the comments, if I ran the query `select category_id from       kirtan_list` I get the following output:

```
1,2
3
```

So when I ran your original query
    select cat_eng_name from category_list  where id in (select category_id from       kirtan_list)

sqlite will try find all rows from `category_list` whose `id` column contains the value `3` or `1,2` (as a single string). Clearly there is no such row. There are rows whose id is `1` or `2`, but that's different than `1,2`.

Comment: select cat_eng_name from category_list  where id in (select group_concat(category_id) from kirtan_list) by this query is this possible?

Comment: `select group_concat(category_id) from kirtan_list` returns a single row containing a single a column, the string `1,2,3`. You want to return multiple rows; specifically, in this case, you need to return 3 rows, containing the values `1`, `2`, and `3`.